# PHP SDK won't run my php-cgi

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying get the helloworld example for the Google Appengine PHP SDK working, but I can't seem to get the dev_appserver to even run. This is the command line I use and the error I get:

```
$ /opt/google-appengine-php/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi src
INFO     2013-06-14 02:50:09,070 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-06-14 02:50:09,331 sdk_update_checker.py:260] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
INFO     2013-06-14 02:50:09,458 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:39069
INFO     2013-06-14 02:50:09,647 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-06-14 02:50:09,650 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-06-14 02:50:09,717 php_runtime.py:199] The PHP runtime is not available because: No input file specified.
```

The output from `php-cgi -v` is:

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jun  7 2013 05:55:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

The output from `whereis php-cgi` is:

```
php-cgi: /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

I looked at the php_runtime.py file but I can't even find the string `No input file specified` so I'm stumped!

Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

**EDIT:** I just tried running `fgrep -r 'No input file specified' *` in the App Engine directory and nothing shows up!!!

**EDIT 2:** It seems the message *No input file specified* comes from the PHP interpreter, no the App Engine SDK. But I still have no idea why?! the `app.yaml` and `helloworld.php` files are in the same directory and are copied from the tutorial page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is the way I installed my system. My /home directory is actually a symbolic-link to /var/home (I have two partitions: / and /var) but PHP has a directive to limit where it loads files from, [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). By default it includes /home but PHP resolves symlinks so all my files were coming from /var/home and /var (or anything below) are not included.

So the solution is to replace `/home` with `/var/home` in the `open_basedir` directive of my `/etc/php/php.ini` file.

**EDIT**: Also, since I installed the AppEngine PHP SDK in `/opt/google-appengine-php` I had to add that directory to `open_basedir` too.